# Как сделать поиск по дате в ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, mysql, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Не могу настроить в приложении поиск записи по дате

У меня есть 3 поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск по заказчикам и материалу работает как нужно, писал как:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OrdersByCustomers(string name)
    {
        var allOrdersByCustomers = db.Orders
            .Where(a => a.Customer.CustomerName.Contains(name))
            .Include(p => p.Customer)
            .Include(p => p.Material)
            .ToList();

        if (allOrdersByCustomers.Count >= 0)
        {
            return View(allOrdersByCustomers);
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OrdersByMaterials(string name)
    {
        var allOrdersByMaterials = db.Orders
            .Where(a => a.Material.Name.Contains(name))
            .Include(p => p.Customer)
            .Include(p => p.Material)
            .ToList();

        if (allOrdersByMaterials.Count >= 0)
        {
            return View(allOrdersByMaterials);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Но не получается сделать поиск по дате, пытаюсь писать как:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OrdersByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var allOrdersByDate = db.Orders
            .Where(a => a.Date.Contains(date)) //В этом моменте дает ошибку, говорит, что дата не может Contains
            .Include(p => p.Customer)
            .Include(p => p.Material)
            .ToList();

        if (allOrdersByDate.Count >= 0)
        {
            return View(allOrdersByDate);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Как можно реализовать поиск по дате если делать так, как у меня, либо если есть предложения, как сделать поиск по всем признакам через одно поле - ответьте пожалуйста...

Опыта мало, а других идей нет, поэтому прошу о помощи здесь

Comment: Почему строка на входе, если вам нужна дата? `string date`

Comment: @tym32167, да, спасибо за это, поменял на DateTime. А в остальном как?

Comment: `.Where(a => a.Date == date)`?

Comment: @tym32167, да, это работает, в контроллере ошибок нет, но программа теперь не видит вообще никакие записи с датой, будь поле пустым, либо соответствующим одной из записей

Comment: Пустым поле быть не может, так как DateTime структура. Вам придется поглядеть, что за данные вы храните в бд, чтобы понять почему у вас пусто в ответах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `.Equals(date)` для сравнения. А так я предлагаю использовать интервал и сравнивать на включение, а не на точное значение

Comment: Да, это работает в контроллере и по идее должно работать в целом, но почему-то он не видит записи. В других двух полях, если они пустые, выводятся все записи, если заполнено - конкретное, если пробовать ваше решение - не выводятся ни как, пустая таблица. Не знаете, в чем может быть проблема? А вообще спасибо больше и на этом

Comment: Ответ один думаю вам нужно посмотреть на сами данные и попытаться сравнить. Правильней умаю привести оба к одному формату, без времени тупо округлить до дня обе части сравнения